# Button arrangement on a full-screen window

Tags: qt, qt4, qt5

My intention is to provide a GUI with two sections, one of which displays k buttons, where k is the number of .txt files in a specific folder. I would be glad to know that there is a way to to simply add buttons (largest possible), still “nicely” arranged in a full screen window. In other words, I would like to only add push buttons, and these would be automatically arranged for me (no specification of coordinates and sizes).

The initial window should be full screen, and buttons should be as large as possible. Any description on how this might be achieved, with pointers to existing examples, is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [Qt Layouts](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/layout.html), for exactly this kind of problem.

A simple example might look something like:

```
QStringList myListOfFiles;

QWidget *parentWidget; // The widget you want to put them into
QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
foreach(QString file, myListOfFiles)
{
     QPushButton *button = new QPushButton(fileName,this);
     layout->addWidget(button);
}
parentWidget->setLayout(layout);
```

This will arrange the buttons in one vertical column, and will be as wide as the parent widget. You could look at [QGridLayout](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgridlayout.html) if you need more than one column.